# Get PHAsset using local image URL or UIIMage?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, phasset

I want to get PHAsset by using local image URl or UIImage. How can I get PHAsset using URl or UIImage?

Comment: Whaddya mean? Elaborate on your question.

Comment: @staticVoidMan I am storing image into document Directory. I am storing photoAsset.localIdentifier into core data  to get again images.So When I store image into Document Directory, I do not have localIdentifier.Thats why I want to get PHAsset using UIImage.

Comment: Why don't you name image with `localIdentifier` when saving in documents so that you can retrieve back with the same identifier.

Comment: @PankajJangid You mean you will provide a `UIImage` object from your document directory to get same image as a `PHAsset` from your iOS gallery!? Like a reverse-image search??

Comment: @staticVoidMan  Yes...

Comment: @PankajJangid There is no API in `PhotoKit` that will take a `UIImage` and check if that exact same image is in the iOS Gallery. I'd rather suggest you to store the `localIdentifier` and link it to the path of the `UIImage` that you save in your documents directory. Later when you are generating the path of the `UIImage`, check your core data for it's related identifier.

Comment: @PankajJangid Also, if you could elaborate on what you have done & what's the purpose of it, then maybe someone can suggest another solution or a new way of looking at it. In my opinion, what you're doing is silly but I don't know your exact use case so can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you

//step1:- import Photos

//step2:- when you presenting imagepicker controller

```
    if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized || PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized{
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self](_) in
        // Present the UIImagePickerController
        self?.present(self!.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

## swift 4.2

```
extension ViewController:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        //obtaining saving path
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        let imagePath = documentsPath?.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
        print(imagePath ?? "N0 imagePath found")
        // extract image from the picker and save it
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

            let imageData = pickedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)
            try! imageData?.write(to: imagePath!)
        }

        let identifier = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset)?.localIdentifier
        print(identifier)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

## swift 3.0 and swift4.0

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    //obtaining saving path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    let imagePath = documentsPath?.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
    // extract image from the picker and save it
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.75)
        data.write(toFile: localPath!, atomically: true)
    }

    let identifier = (info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset)?. localIdentifier
    print(identifier)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks